# How do I get a deleted icon(widget) back in KDE Search & Launch?

Tags: debian, kde, desktop

This has happened to me before, but I wasn't able to google a proper answer: I didn't have a habit of locking my widgets in KDE(Needless to say, I do now) and once in a blue moon I delete an icon from my Search & Launch strip that's positioned right below the task manager. I try launching a program, but sometimes I hit the "minus" sign and adios, icon! Is there a way to undelete it and get it back?
My screen looks kind of like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740024/where-did-search-and-launch-layout-go-in-kde-plasma-5). I've scoured all the configuration files in the .kde directory in the hopes of finding a list of my current icons. So far-zip-o! I frequently back up my home directory so I might find my original list of icons there if only I knew where to look! Is there such a file?
This might be the most improper forum for such comments, but at times like these I dearly miss Windows!

Answer (score 0):

Got it! [Here's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171119/how-to-control-kde-4-9-0-plasma-widgets-from-command-line) the file that I was looking for. If you have the same setup mentioned in this post, this might be useful to you: on line 531 of the `~/.kde/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc` file is a list of your "stripwidget favoUrites". This is where your Search & Launch icons are stored(in logical order, of course), among all the other, useful settings!

I just popped into the backup file and found what I needed.

PS: If there's another way to go about the situation, ie. something lame like "taking the icon out of the trash and putting it back into the launcher"-please, do chime in!